# Combine two data fields(columns) values and display in Listbox-ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to select data from Microsoft SQL Server and concatenate two of its column values and display it in ListBox.

For example - there are two columns in SQL, namely Software name and Software-users. A single software has N number of users what I want to do is select the software name in SQL and concatenate it with Software users name and display it in the listbox.

So far I tried this, but the listbox displays null.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [SWName] +'-'+ [SWUser] as Creator from AllSWUsers WHERE SWName = @SWName", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SWName", Global.usrlsts);
SqlDataAdapter daFill = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
daFill.Fill(ds);
lstUsers.DataSource = ds;
lstUsers.DataTextField = "Creator";
lstUsers.DataValueField = "SWName";
lstUsers.DataBind();
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query returns data?

Comment: 2 things to try. First try your query in sql and see that it returns data. Second, debug and check that 'ds' gets filled. Also where are you getting the DataValueField "SWName" from?

Comment: Note that in SQLServer if any string is null in a `string1+string2+string3...` scenario, the whole string becomes null. It may be preferable to use `CONCAT`

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the reason you are not selecting `SWName` in your query but you are using that column as shown below in your code.

```
lstUsers.DataValueField = "SWName";
```

Try this

```
Select ISNULL([SWName], '') as [SWName], ISNULL([SWName],'') +'-'+ ISNULL([SWUser], '') as Creator from AllSWUsers WHERE SWName = @SWName
```

Comment: @santosh You have not updated your question as I am saying that you are using the column SWName in C# which is not returning by your select statement.